# Is there any way to make the Entire Screen Read Only in wpf

Tags: wpf

On click of a button I need to freeze (Read Only) the entire screen even the menus / tab controls is there any possibility to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `Application.Current.MainWindow.IsEnabled=false`? That should propagate down to all other controls which have not overriden `IsEnabled`.

If you're looking for MVVM way: [Disable WPF buttons during longer running process, the MVVM way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143683/disable-wpf-buttons-during-longer-running-process-the-mvvm-way)

Comment: Thanks.. This code makes the page as Read Only. I am having a long running process and shown the progress using ProgressRing this ring is not displaying only the page is set to read only.